# How can I highlight a keywordsprefix in listings?

Tags: listings, highlighting, keywords

Ok, so here's my problem which I'm repeatedly gnawing on, whenever I try to typset source code. To this day, I have not found someone on the internet asking for the same problem.

I want to add a `keywordsprefix` so that everything starting with a `&` is highlighted as a keyword. Here's a MWE illustrating my problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lispgreen}{RGB}{154, 228, 151}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.97}
\definecolor{violet}{rgb}{0.8, 0, 0.7}

\lstset{language=Lisp,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
        keywordsprefix=&,
        keywordstyle=\color{lispgreen!70!black},
        stringstyle=\color{violet},
        showstringspaces=false,
        backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
        frame=single}

\begin{lstlisting}
(defmacro simple-incf (var &optional (amount 1)) 
    (list setq var (list + var amount)))
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Now, a in a statement like `&optional`, everything *except* the ampersand is highlighted, which looks profoundly weird to me. Maybe other people use other editors or settings, but by default, my vim will highlight also the keyword prefix itself so this is what I see daily.

My question now is, can I somehow tell `listings` to either extend the highlighting to include also the prefixes or, alternatively, just brutely make that one character `&` highlighted everywhere (which in this case would also solve the problem)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to highlight the keyword prefix too you have to change the category from *other* to *letter*. See table 2: Standard character table of the listings documentation.

To achieve this you can use the option `alsoletter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lispgreen}{RGB}{154, 228, 151}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.97}
\definecolor{violet}{rgb}{0.8, 0, 0.7}

\lstset{language=Lisp,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
        keywordsprefix=\&,alsoletter=\&,% 
        keywordstyle=\color{lispgreen!70!black},
        stringstyle=\color{violet},
        showstringspaces=false,
        backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
        frame=single}

\begin{lstlisting}
(defmacro simple-incf (var &optional (amount 1)) 
    (list setq var (list + var amount)))
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]